# Generating weekly dates

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, silverlight, date

I am sure this has been done before so i am looking for an efficient solution instead of own custom solution.

Given 2 dates, I am trying to generate the accurate weekly date (for creating weekly orders).

EDIT: I need to use .NET standard library to do this.

```
Example below,

Given 28/02/2012 and 6/03/2012.

so, the weekly dates generated are
- Week From(Start Monday):   Week To(End Sunday):
- 27/02/2012               - 04/03/2012
- 05/03/2012               - 11/03/2012

Another example (1 month)

Given 01/02/2012 and 29/02/2012
so, the weekly dates generated are
- Week From(Start Monday):   Week To(End Sunday):
- 30/01/2012               - 05/02/2012
- 06/02/2012               - 12/02/2012
- 13/02/2012               - 19/02/2012
- 20/02/2012               - 26/02/2012
- 27/02/2012               - 04/03/2012
```

I am doing this in c#. Has this been done before? Mind sharing the solutions?

Cheers

Comment: My solution does not take into account the starting date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com). Admittedly it requires a `<=` operator which I'm just implementing right now - but that shouldn't take long :)

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowDates(new LocalDate(2012, 2, 28), new LocalDate(2012, 3, 6));
        ShowDates(new LocalDate(2012, 2, 1), new LocalDate(2012, 2, 29));
    }

    static void ShowDates(LocalDate start, LocalDate end)
    {
        // Previous is always strict - increment start so that
        // it *can* be the first day, then find the previous
        // Monday
        var current = start.PlusDays(1).Previous(IsoDayOfWeek.Monday);
        while (current <= end)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", current,
                              current.Next(IsoDayOfWeek.Sunday));
            current = current.PlusWeeks(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously it's possible to do this in normal `DateTime` as well, but there's no real representation of "just a date" which makes the code less clear - and you'd need to implement `Previous` yourself.

EDIT: For example, in this case you might use:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowDates(new DateTime(2012, 2, 28), new DateTime(2012, 3, 6));
        ShowDates(new DateTime(2012, 2, 1), new DateTime(2012, 2, 29));
    }

    static void ShowDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        // In DateTime, 0=Sunday
        var daysToSubtract = ((int) start.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;
        var current = start.AddDays(-daysToSubtract);        

        while (current <= end)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", current, current.AddDays(6));
            current = current.AddDays(7);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway of using the standard .net library? I can't use third party dll at the moment. Cheers

Comment: @overule: As I said - yes, but you'll need to find code to work out the relevant day of the week. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to figure out that the start date is a monday:

```
var slots = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();
DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 2, 28);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 3, 6);
for (DateTime i = start; i < end; i = i.AddDays(7))
{
    slots.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(i, i.AddDays(6)));
}

foreach (var slot in slots)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", slot.Item1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), slot.Item2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```

Edit: Assuming you have to figure out what monday and what sunday covers the date range, you can move one day backwards till you hit a monday, and a day forward till you hit a sunday.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var slots = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();
        DateTime start = FirstMonday(new DateTime(2012, 2, 28));
        DateTime end = FirstSunday(new DateTime(2012, 3, 6));
        for (DateTime i = start; i < end; i = i.AddDays(7))
        {
            slots.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(i, i.AddDays(6)));
        }

        foreach (var slot in slots)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", slot.Item1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), slot.Item2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static DateTime FirstMonday(DateTime date)
    {
        while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) date = date.AddDays(-1);
        return date;
    }
    static DateTime FirstSunday(DateTime date)
    {
        while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) date = date.AddDays(1);
        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that the start days in the examples *aren't* Mondays, I think figuring that out is part of the job.

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows you to customize your start and end DayOfWeek:

**Solution:**

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> GetWeeklyDateTimes(DateTime from, DateTime to, DayOfWeek startDay, DayOfWeek endDay)
    {
        int startEndSpan = 7 - endDay - startDay;

        // Subtract days until it falls on our desired start day
        from = from.AddDays(startDay - from.DayOfWeek);
        // Add days until it falls on our desired end day
        to = to.AddDays(to.DayOfWeek - endDay + 2);

        Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> dateTimes = new Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();

        while (to.Subtract(from).Days > startEndSpan)
        {
            dateTimes.Add(from, from.AddDays(startEndSpan));

            from = from.AddDays(startEndSpan + 1);
        }

        return dateTimes;
    }
```

**Example Usage:**

```
// DateTime(2012, 2, 1) corresponds to Year 2012, Month February, Day 1
Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> dateTimes = GetWeeklyDateTimes(new DateTime(2012, 2, 1), new DateTime(2012, 2, 29), DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Sunday);

foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, DateTime> entry in dateTimes)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(entry.Key.ToString() + "     " + entry.Value.ToString());
}
```